# One-to-Many EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Possuo 2 classes, Topic e Users.

Basicamente um usuário pode ter vários tópicos porém o tópico pode ter somente um usuário (criador).

Ao tentar criar uma Migration, deu o seguinte erro:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Topic.Users' of type 'Users'. Either manually configure the
>   relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Eu sei que a feature de many-to-many ainda não foi implementada no EF Core 3.0, mas o que eu fiz de errado para não fazer o mapeamento automático?

```
    public class Topic : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Users Users { get; set; }

    public CategoryTopic Categories { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Answers> Answers { get; set; }

    public int UpVotes { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EditedAt { get; set; }

    public int DownVotes { get; set; }

    public bool Closed { get; set; }

    public Users ClosedBy { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
    public class Users : Entity
{
    public enum UsersType { Member, Moderator, Admin }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UsersType UserType { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BannedUntil { get; set; }

    public int BannedTimes { get; set; }

    public int Reputation { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Coloquei [NotMapped] na propriedade Users porém também não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que fazer o relacionamento manualmente no meu Context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder moodelbuilder)
{
    moodelbuilder.Entity<Topic>().HasOne(x => x.CreatedBy);
    moodelbuilder.Entity<Topic>().HasOne(x => x.ClosedBy);
    moodelbuilder.Entity<Users>().HasMany(x => x.Topics);

}
```